# What will happen if I abort in tf checkin

Tags: tfs

I was using tf command to checkin my code. And then I suddenly found out there are files I don't want to checkin. So I pressed Ctrl+C to abort. Will that left any partial submission on TFS?

Or there is a transaction will guarantee only complete checkin will be rolled to the system?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tfs checkins are atomic transactions. Either everything is checked in or nothing is.

Comment: Can you provide any reference? Thanks!

Comment: Ref: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dajung/archive/2013/04/25/tfs-tidbits-the-atomic-check-in.aspx